# Android Listview with different layout for each row Java NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview

Solved! Look at the edit below!

I am trying to create a list view to show different type of layouts but am getting this error

(I am getting this error when I scroll up, after scrolling down and seeing both types of layouts)

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I can scroll to the bottom and see both types of layouts (couldn't see them both at once (error) when the else statement with the comment "//THIS ONE!" want there)

Code for my adapter is as follows - (edited as with @matiash's suggestions)

```
    public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsXMLData> {

    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public NewsAdapter(Context ctx, int textViewResourceId, List<NewsXMLData> sites) {
        super(ctx, textViewResourceId, sites);




        //Setup the ImageLoader, we'll use this to display our images
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(ctx).build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

        //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .build();


    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

       if(getItem(position).getType().equals("image")) {

            return TYPE_ITEM;

       }

       else{

            return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView iconImg = null;
        public TextView contentTxt = null;
        public TextView imageTitleTxt = null ;
        public ProgressBar imageIndicator = null ;
        public TextView textTitleTxt = null ;
        public ProgressBar textIndicator = null;
    }




    String flag;
    //@Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder =null;
        int type = getItemViewType(pos);
        Log.i("APP", "getView " + pos + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        View row = convertView;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        try {

            if (null == row) {
                //No recycled View, we have to inflate one.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type){
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        row = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_news, null);

                        holder.iconImg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsImageView);
                        holder.imageTitleTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTitleText);
                        holder.imageIndicator = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.newsProgressBar);
                        holder.iconImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.imageIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imageTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //Setup a listener we can use to swtich from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
                        ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener() {


                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                        };
                        holder.iconImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imageIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.imageTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         //Load the image and use our options so caching is handled.
                        imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(pos).getImgUrl(), holder.iconImg, options, listener);
                        //Set the relavent text in our TextViews
                        holder.imageTitleTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getTitle());
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        row = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_news_text, null);
                        holder.contentTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTextContentText);
                        holder.textTitleTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTextTitleText);
                        holder.textIndicator = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTextProgressBar);

                        /*holder.contentTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.textIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.textTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/


                        holder.contentTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.textIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.textTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.textTitleTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getTitle());
                        holder.contentTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getContent());
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return row;


    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Also, is there a better way to do it other than parsing XML and showing the content as a list view?

Edit: The code now works thanks to @Jens and @matiash
Code:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsXMLData> {

    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public NewsAdapter(Context ctx, int textViewResourceId, List<NewsXMLData> sites) {
        super(ctx, textViewResourceId, sites);




        //Setup the ImageLoader, we'll use this to display our images
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(ctx).build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

        //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .build();


    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

       if(getItem(position).getType().equals("image")) {

            return TYPE_ITEM;

       }

       else{

            return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView iconImg = null;
        public TextView contentTxt = null;
        public TextView imageTitleTxt = null ;
        public ProgressBar imageIndicator = null ;
        public TextView textTitleTxt = null ;
        public ProgressBar textIndicator = null;
    }




    String flag;
    //@Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder =null;
        int type = getItemViewType(pos);
        //Log.i("APP", "getView " + pos + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        View row = convertView;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        try {

            if (null == row) {
                //No recycled View, we have to inflate one.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        row = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_news, null);


                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        row = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_news_text, null);

                        break;
                }
                //Log.i("APP","holder" + holder);
            }
                if(type==TYPE_ITEM){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.iconImg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsImageView);
                holder.imageTitleTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTitleText);
                holder.imageIndicator = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.newsProgressBar);
                holder.iconImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.imageIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Setup a listener we can use to swtich from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
                ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                };
                holder.iconImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.imageTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Load the image and use our options so caching is handled.
                imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(pos).getImgUrl(), holder.iconImg, options, listener);
                //Set the relavent text in our TextViews
                holder.imageTitleTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getTitle());
            }
            else if(type==TYPE_SEPARATOR){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.contentTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTextContentText);
                holder.textTitleTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTextTitleText);
                holder.textIndicator = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.newsTextProgressBar);

                        /*holder.contentTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.textIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.textTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/


                holder.contentTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.textIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.textTitleTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.textTitleTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getTitle());
                holder.contentTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getContent());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return row;


    }

}
```

Comment: Is it string comparing `if(type=="image")` correctly?

Comment: Add a stacktrace please. In which line you get the NPE

Comment: @Braj Yes sir it is correct.

Comment: @Jens How can I do that?

Comment: @Jens I surrounded the whole function in a try block and now when I scroll up the list view some "image" layouts are getting swapped with "text" layouts. Still getting the same error in logcat.

Comment: @user3712483 please post the logcat entry with the whole stacktrace. So we can help you.

Comment: @Jens I changed the code a bit as per matiash's comment. Here is the logcat - http://pastebin.com/PYgXF6ie now it is showing all the layouts properly but gives errors when the activity is launched (see logcat).

Comment: You get the NPE in `com.justduthings.companion.NewsAdapter.getView(NewsAdapter.java:172)` Which line is it?

Comment: @Jens     `convertView.setTag(holder);` this is line 172 currently.

Comment: @user3712483 Looks like holder is null. Can you check this using the debugger?

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot! It works now. I removed `convertView.setTag(holder);` and it works properly, without any errors now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually convertView is null here. you should be putting like `row.setTag(holder)`. On first run convertView will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Holder` is null. Can you check this using the debugger. Remove the line 172 in `com.justduthings.companion.NewsAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. One more question, I want to update "news" dynamically is there a better way to do this other than parsing XML and showing the content as a list view?

Comment: Actually convertView is null here. you should be putting like `row.setTag(holder)`. On first run convertView will be null.

Comment: @DineshBalu Why is setTag required? It is working fine without it. Please tell what is its function.

Comment: Now your are not using the ViewHolder that you were using before. Why were you having a ViewHolder object?. The purpose of ViewHolder is that you don't have to do things like `findViewById` everytime the view is drawn. Now you are just creating a ViewHolder instance and assigning view references to it unnecessarily . You can create ViewHolder instance once , set it as tag for the row view and use it later to update the child views.

Comment: @DineshBalu Is my way of doing it wrong? So, if I use setTag then I can put all the `findViewById` statements in `if (row==null)` block?

Comment: You are not doing entirely wrong , just not the recommended best way.Yes you can. Otherwise how are you gonna update row on scrolling now !!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `if (type=="image")` or `flag != type` is not the correct way to compare Strings in Java. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). This means that your code won't do what you expect, using the incorrect ifs all the way down

Secondly, for ListViews such as these, with "mixed" item views, there is a much more elegant (and built-in) solution. By implementing [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) (returning 2) and [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) (returning the type of each item) the framework can keep different recycling lists for the different view types.

This means that you can trust that when you get passed a non-null `convertView`, it will be one you inflated for the same item type (and you can dispense with the `flag!=type` check entirely).

Comment: I edited the code (please see OP). I am still getting the error when I start the activity(Although the list is getting populated properly). After scrolling up and down a few times there are is no error. Logcat - http://pastebin.com/PYgXF6ie